# Can transitive verbs not be followed by an object?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, objects

Here's an example of a transitive verb "*found*" not followed by an object. Can anyone tell me what kind of sentence structure is that which makes this possible?

> Some people with pain, anxiety or depression who obtain medical marijuana cards may overuse marijuana within a short time frame, leading to cannabis use disorder while failing to improve their symptoms, a new study found.

Comment: If there is no object, the verb is functioning intransitively. "Found" has no object in your example, so it is intransitive. It's best to consider the _uses_ of verbs. Some verbs like "find" can be either transitive or intransitive, depending on whether they have an object.

Answer (score 5):

This only looks like the transitive verb 'found' is not followed by an object because of the sentence structure (which is quite often used in medical research news reports). The basic sentence here is "A new study found something about some people", specifically "that some people ... may overuse marijuana ...".
[Edited after BillJ's answer and comments. A transitive verb must be followed by a noun phrase. The original question assumes that **find** is *always* transitive, but it can also be intransitive. Two example sentences are "The judge found *for the plaintiff*" and "The judge found *that the defendant was a liar*" (which is similar to your example sentence. Either way, **find** *must* be followed by *something*. And it is still true that the research found *something*.]

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say. The sentence is interpreted as "A new study found (that) some people with pain, anxiety or depression who obtain medical marijuana cards may overuse marijuana within a short time frame, leading to cannabis use disorder while failing to improve their symptoms". In other words the _that_ clause is complement of "found".

Comment: Thanks. Transitive verbs are defined as those requiring a direct object. There is no term for a verb requiring a complement. The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language says that complements are sometimes obligatory and sometimes not. Most verbs allow more than one pattern of complementation. It contains a section on "constructions containing a declarative content clause [usually, one starting with 'that']" and a sub-section "content clause as the only internal complement". 'Find' is listed among the relevant verbs. So 'find' needs *something* after it, whether DO, PC or 'it + ad to V'.

Comment: Yes, "find" requires a complement of some kind. Leaving aside a few special exceptions, direct objects are always NPs not clauses. I take the initial clause in the OP's example to be a complement, not object, of "find". Note that objects are a distinct subtype of complement, not to be confused with clausal complements.

Comment: @Sydney If you're looking for a term for a verb that requires one complement (not necessarily a DO), consider "divalent".

Answer (score 0):

> [*Some people with pain, anxiety or depression who obtain medical*
> *marijuana cards may overuse marijuana within a short time frame,*
> *leading to cannabis use disorder while failing to improve their*
> *symptoms*]*, a new study **found***.

The rule is that if there is no object, the verb is functioning intransitively. "Found" has no object in your example, so it is intransitive.

We need to distinguish between verbs like "find", which can be either transitive (*I found my keys*) or intransitive (*The court found in her favour*), and verbs like "inspect", "anger", "annihilate", etc., which are always transitive.

At first glance it may seem that the long initial expression *Some people ...* is functioning as some kind of preposed object of "found". But it's not a noun phrase and thus it cannot be an object. In fact it's a clause with a subject-predicate structure functioning as complement of "found".

We can paraphrase the sentences as:

*A new study found (that) some people with pain, anxiety or depression who obtain medical marijuana cards may overuse marijuana within a short time frame, leading to cannabis use disorder while failing to improve their symptoms.*

Comment: On further thought, I think the problem is the original poster's assumption that 'find' is (always) transitive. Oxford and Merriam-Webster both list 'find' as mostly transitive but with one intransitive definition (with the example 'found for the defendant'). I can't seen an example like 'found that the defendant was not guilty' (but most of the time we would say 'found the defendant not guilty' anyway).

Comment: @Sydney The problem with dictionaries is that they consider content (_that_) clauses to be objects, whereas they are best analysed as complements. In my grammar (and that of CGEL) the _that_ clause here is not object but complement of "feel":  _I realise [that you feel insulted}_.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you. But for practical general ELL purposes, it is *usually* sufficient to treat SVO and SVC as roughly equivalent (in fact those two are sometimes combined as SVX.) (Someone else downvoted your answer. I upvoted it.)

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is in an unusual order, for English: object-subject-verb.

It’s often used with subordinate clauses.  “People don’t like know-it-alls, I found,” means the same thing as, “I found [that] people don’t like know-it-alls.”  The clause (with the word *that* omitted) is the object of the verb *found*, and is a rare example of a direct object that can be moved before the subject.  This works with other verbs and clauses, such as “It was raining, I saw.”  (Compare: “I saw [that] it was raining.”)  Another context where this is frequently used is something like, “‘Hello!’ I said.”

We would not, however, normally use this with other kinds of predicates.  “I found many people smarter than me,” would not normally be rearranged into object-subject-verb order. (“Many people smarter than me I found.”)  Yoda from *Star Wars* was in fact written this way to emphasize how alien he was; it’s meant to sound like he’s thinking in some other language.

This sentence structure does, however, appear more frequently in early-modern English, where it is called a periodic sentence.  It hung on longer in poetry, where word order is much more flexible.  (2022 is the one hundredth anniversary of Robert Frost’s “Stopping by Woods on a Snowy Evening,” which begins with the famous line, “Whose woods these are I think I know.”)  Even this, however, is becoming less common now that poems are less likely to rhyme or follow strict meter.

Comment: Yes, but note that In "I found [many people smarter than me]", the bracketed element is an NP functioning as object of "found". But in "[People don’t like know-it-alls], I found", the bracketed element is not an NP functioning as object but a clause functioining as complement of "found".

Comment: @BillJ Would you accept, “People don’t like know-it-alls, I found **out**,” as more unambiguously an example of OSV word order?

Comment: @BillJ Or, since I said it’s more common in poetry, Robert Frost’s line, “Whose woods these are I think I know,” or Oscar Wilde’s, “And, though I was a soul in pain, / My pain I could not feel”? Even “Stopping by Woods on a Snowy Evening” is a century old this year, though.

Comment: No: in "[People don’t like know-it-alls], I found out", the bracketed expression cannot be the object of "found" because it's the object of the preposition "out". "Found" is thus intransitive.

Comment: @BillJ i  respectfully disagree; “found out” and “found” are both transitive verbs in that example. There’s no other way to parse, “I found [out] that people don’t ...” than reading the “that” clause as the object of the verb.

Comment: Are you taking "found out" to be a so-called phrasal verb? Not that it makes any difference, since clauses don't function as objects of verbs, but as some other kind of complement.

Comment: @BillJ Yes. In this context, *found out* is synonymous with “found,” and “out” is clearly not being used as a separate preposition with its normal meaning. (I didn’t discover it outside.) Nor can a clause such as that be the object of *out*.

Comment: You're assuming that clauses can be objects, which is not the case. For example, in "I found out [where they hid the key]", the bracketed element is not an object but a subordinate interrogative clause functioning as complement, licensed by the verbal idiom "found out". In virtually all cases, objects have the form of NPs, not clauses. Note also that _that_ clauses are virtually always complements, not objects.

Comment: Incidentally, the term 'phrasal verb' is a misnomer. In, for example, "They found out", it's not the whole expression "found out" that is a verb, but just the word "found". This is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have  _They had found out_, but not _*They had find outed_

Comment: @BillJ You appear to think the usual vocabulary we use to talk about English grammar is in some sense incorrect, and prefer your own. This makes the conversation very confusing, especially to someone learning English.

Comment: @BillJ What I think is important here is that, in the sentences, “I thought it was raining. Did she see this? Yes, she confirmed it. It was raining, she said,” the clause “it was raining” clearly functions as the object of transitive verbs. It can be replaced by the pronouns *it*, *this* or *that*. It can also be moved into initial position, which is very unusual for direct objects in contemporary American English.

Comment: In the case of direct reported speech, the reported speech is not regarded as an object. It's either a main clause, as in _'It was raining', she said_, (where the reporting frame is a parenthetical), or a complement of the reporting verb, as in _She said 'It was raining'_.

Comment: @BillJ I think we’ve drifted pretty far from the original topic, and this discussion isn’t going to improve my answer. Thanks for the feedback.